# Searching for value with hyphen in DB (SQLite3)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having problems searching my database (SQLite3) for existing values. I think the problem is that the search value contains a hyphen. It's working when I try the command in a database editor with "" and '', but can't seem to get it working in my code.

I added the entire code if that helps. The part that's not working is after **if re.findall("[i|I][t|T]-", str(i))** in the class Arbetsgivare.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import sqlite3

class Connect():

    def __init__(self):  
        global conn
        conn = sqlite3.connect('DBJobb.db')
        global cursor
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print("DB successfully connected.")        
        try:
            conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE Annonser(TITLE TEXT NOT NULL, URL TEXT NOT NULL)''')
            print("The DB was created successfully.")
        except:
            print("The table already exists, no need to create it.")

class Arbetsgivare:

    def Polisen():
        url = requests.get('http://polisen.se/aktuellt/lediga-jobb')
        content = url.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
        added = 0
        notadded = 0

        for i in soup.find_all('a'):
            if re.findall("[i|I][t|T]\-", str(i)):
                #SELECT both with * and count(*)
                conn.execute("SELECT * FROM Annonser WHERE TITLE = ?", (i.get_text(),))
                search = cursor.fetchone() 
                print(search) #Just to see what the value it has.
                if search is None: #I have tried with == 0 as well.
                    conn.execute("INSERT INTO Annonser(TITLE, URL) values (?, ?)", ((i.get_text()), ('http://polisen.se'+i.get('href'))))
                    conn.commit()
                    added = added + 1
                else:
                    notadded = notadded + 1
        print(str(added)+" entries was added to the DB. There were "+str(notadded)+" entries found which was already in the DB.")

Connect()
Arbetsgivare.Polisen()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got it to work. The problem was the brackets and the commas and using contents instead of get_text(). Here is the working code.

```
for i in soup.find_all('a'):
            if re.findall("[i|I][t|T]\-", str(i)):
                var = str(i.contents)
                var = var.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("'", "")
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Annonser WHERE TITLE = ?", (var,))
                search = cursor.fetchone() 
                if search is None:
                    conn.execute("INSERT INTO Annonser(TITLE, URL) values (?, ?)", ((i.get_text()), ('http://polisen.se'+i.get('href'))))
                    conn.commit()
                    added = added + 1
                else:
                    notadded = notadded + 1
        print(str(added)+" entrie(s) was added from SKL to the DB.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes

```
SELECT * FROM Annonser WHERE TITLE = 'searchstring'
```

Comment: Please tell me how. I've tried some ways but they are not working.

Comment: """SELECT * FROM Annonser WHERE TITLE = '%s' """%(urstring)